# WINAPI to get device status

Tags: winapi, device-driver

Is there any WINAPI call available to get the status of a particular device. I am able to get a handle to the device using the calls:

- `SetupDiGetClassDevs`
- `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`
- `SetupDiSetSelectedDevice`

But I want to uninstall the device only if the status shows error code 28. (Please refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125174 for error codes).

From my previous post here, i got to know how to uninstall a device and that is working perfectly fine for me.

I just need to know how to get the device status using a WINAPI call.

Please guide.

Comment: That's not a `HANDLE` you have.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CM_Get_DevNode_Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538514%28VS.85%29.aspx) the status code you look for is outout as `pulProblemNumber`